# Why can't this be done with if?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to handle errors received from an async call:

```
let res: Result<TcpStream, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> = session.runtime().borrow_mut().block_on(async {
    let fut = TcpStream::connect(session.configuration().socket()).await?;
    Ok(fut)
});
```

I tried to do it the old school way with an if but the compiler didn't like it:

```
if res.is_err() {
    return Err(res);
}
```

After some googling I came across this:

```
let mut stream = match res {
    Ok(res) => res,
    Err(res) => return Err(res),
};
```

which feels very much the same but with Rusts' equivalent of a switch statement. Why can't I use the `if`?

Comment: The `match` statment is returning the value inside the `Err` enum; your if statement is attempting to wrap an `Err` inside an `Err`.  This might be more clear if you renamed the values on the left hand side of your match arrow from `res` to something else.

Comment: You should include the full error message from the compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if res.is_err() { return res }` should work. `Result` is an enum with two variants: `Ok` which by convention holds a "successful" result, and `Err` which holds error information. As John [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64323838/why-cant-this-be-done-with-if/64324262#comment113744422_64323838), wrapping the existing `Result` (which happens to hold an `Err`) in another `Err` result doesn't make sense - or, more precisely, doesn't match the return type of the function.

When you use `match`, you unpack the result into its constituent values, and then in the error case re-pack it into a new result. Note that instead of the `match` statement use can use the [`?` operator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html#a-shortcut-for-propagating-errors-the--operator), which would compress the declaration to just:

```rust
let mut stream = res?;
```